# Laravel Livewire Failed to Store File

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

I have deployed my Laravel Livewire app on my Ubuntu server (Apache2) and configured it. Livewire is working fine, but when I try to upload an image or any files, it returns an error.

- The error on the Livewire page says "The document failed to upload" (since I set the document as a variable model name). And from the console, it says 500 server error (because I set the production on env, so only that message comes up).
- The error on the laravel.log file says

```
production.ERROR: fopen(/mypath/to/laravel/storage/framework/cache/data/76/e7/76e7c0fdd0cc0d46502f9d381b947cdf6aa69891): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I set the permission for the storage folder, including the folders inside it. I used the `local` disk described as (default)

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
    'throw' => false,
],
```

My variable model for the document

```php
 #[Validate('nullable|max:1024')]
 public $document = null;
 protected string $pathDocument = 'activity/document';
```

My code to save the file

```php
$document = $this->document?->store($this->pathDocument);
```

I appreciate all of your help. Thank you so much.

Edit: The `data` folder inside `/storage/framework/cache/` exists. However, the folders inside it don't (76/e7/76e7xxx). I don't know how to produce the cache folders, as far as I know, they come automatically when we run the app.

Comment: the cache folder has nothing to do with uploading files. Those folders are used to store cached values via the `file` driver when `Cache::put`. Ensure the webserver has permissions to write there. Maybe compare the permissions there with framework/sessions

Comment: @krisgjika yeah, I thought the same thing, but my Livewire always tries to open that folder. The sessions and the cache folder in the framework folder have the same permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem.
Thank you @krisgjika, yes, it's all about permission. My application try to caching the data into `/storage/framework/cache/`, however the storage folder is not completely accessed from public. So I run this 2 commands, and solve the problem

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage
```